# JavaScript Maps -- create two values with "same" key

Tags: javascript

I seem to recall reading somewhere that you could add two entries to a JavaScript map which have the same "key" (more like a label) but they were somehow made unique. These kinds of keys had a special name. I can't find any information anywhere on Google but I am certain I remember reading this. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

The answer will be useful for me in writing my answer to another question on SO.

Edit: I am receiving votes for the question being too broad or unclear but within several minutes I have received the answer I'm looking for from 2 people, therefore I think the down vote and close requests are unmerited. If I could have been more specific I could have found the answer without coming here to ask.

Thanks

Comment: the answer, you got does not match the requirement of **same** keys. symbols are not the same, by definition and any other object as key would serve as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I appreciate this, that's why I put "same" in double quotes and in the question body clarified that the "key" (as I recalled) was actually more like a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are probably talking about Symbols.

A Symbol is created with a string, but is a unique object that you can't recreate and have to keep stored. You can use these as the key to an object and have as many of them as you want:

```js
const a = Symbol('my key');
const b = Symbol('my key');

const map = {};

map[a] = 1;
map[b] = 2;

console.log(map[a]);
console.log(map[b]);
```

Really, you aren't given them the same key (since each Symbol is a unique object), since that is impossible, but this lets you create something with the same value that can be used as a key.